# Can't install Rtools 43 using windows R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt) -- "Eye Holes" & Solution

Tags: r, rstudio, rtools

I'm at the beginning stages of learning R and I'm trying to install Rtools using install.packages("Rtools43") as it's the newest version of R and I keep getting:

Code I wrote: install.packages("Rtools43")

What I got: Warning in install.packages :
package ‘Rtools43’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

So then, I went to the Rtools download and install website (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/rtools.html) and manually installed Rtools 43 using the Rtools 43 installer to my computer. It's successfully downloaded.

From what I've read, now that it's downloaded to my computer I should be able to use it and library it. It hasn't installed to my packages. So I tried to install it using the install packages button in RStudio and install from the Package Archive File(.zip; .tar.gz) option to individually install the packages included in the RTools 43 file that include clang32, clang64, clanarm64, mingw32, mingw64, mysys2, and ucrt64.

Doing this resulted in the following:
Input: install.packages("C:/rtools43/ucrt64.exe", repos = NULL)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Sookr/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Output: Error in install.packages : type == "both" cannot be used with 'repos = NULL'

Please help! What can I do from here??

Edit & Solution: I think I ran and installed Rtools with RStudio still open. So, I followed the advice from the people below. I uninstalled and reinstalled Rtools, then restarted R. I opened RStudio, and I was able to use it!

Thank you to those who commented with solutions; it was super helpful!

Comment: RTools is not an r package. It is a collection of programs that will be installed on your computer outside of R. After you down load the exe, click on it to run the installer. Restart R afterwards so it can find it. You do not need to run install.packages to do anything with RTools

Comment: Rtools43 is not an R package. Start the installer (it's a programm) and follow the instructions.

Comment: If you downloaded the RTools installer for windows, you have to run the .exe to install it. Make sure RStudio is closed when you do.